# Concat function returns the error "is not valid in the context where it is used" (SQLSTATE=42703)

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table - let's call it 'table1'. Within this table is a column in the varchar format - let's call it 'column1'.

I want to insert the date from two days ago into column1 in dd/mm/yyyy format, with " - UK" appended to the end. In other words, the desired result for today would look like this:

```
column1
---------------
01/01/2023 - UK
```

I've written the following code to do this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES
(
CONCAT(VARCHAR_FORMAT((CURRENT DATE - 3 DAYS), 'DD/MM/YYYY'), " - UK")
)
;
```

However, running the code results in this error message:

```
" - UK" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=3.69.56
```

Could anyone tell me where I'm going wrong, please?

Comment: Use single quotes: `' - UK'`. Double quotes are for aliases.

Comment: Of course! Can't believe I missed that. Thank you!